# como usar un if en la asignación de variables en PHP

Tags: php, html, php5

Bien lo que sucede es que quiero hacer una comparacion al realizar una asignacion de variables en PHP pero me manda un error en el IF.

A continuación pongo trato de hacer la asignación de variable usando un IF:

```
$documentoidentidad = if ($_POST['documento']==1){$_POST['cedula']} else {$_POST['cedula1']};
```

Y este es el error que me manda el navegador:

```
(!) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:
```

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 5):

Mas allá de los errores de sintaxis que tienes por la falta de `;` tu lógica me parece mal planteada, si tratas de asignar a `$documentoidentidad` uno de los 2 valores entonces debe ser así

```
<?php 


if ($_POST['documento']==1){
    $documentoidentidad = $_POST['cedula'];
} else 
{
    $documentoidentidad = $_POST['cedula1'];
}
```

- Es decir la variable en cada evaluación: `if` o `else` se le asigna el valor dependiendo de que llega por `$_POST`
- En la llave de cierre del `else` no tiene por que ir un `;`
- Lo que se procesa por dentro de los bloques de las llaves de `if` y `else` son los que llevan punto y coma `;`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tu quieres hacer, se llaman ***operadores ternarios***, y la sintaxis correcta, siguiendo tu ejemplo, sería la siguiente, espero te ayude:

```
$documentoidentidad = ($_POST['documento']==1) ? $_POST['cedula'] : $_POST['cedula1'];

echo $documentoidentidad;
```